# Uploading a file with SendKeys not working in Firefox 55.0.3

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to send the file path to upload button through **SendKeys()** in Firefox, it is giving me an error **"File not found:c:\filename.txt(IndexOutOfBounds)"**.

Code for Upload:

```
    public static void UploadTheFile()
    {
        IWebElement fileUpload = Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("file-upload-input"));
        try
        {
            fileUpload.SendKeys(@"C:\test file.txt");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        //Thread.Sleep(3000);
       _wait.Until(d => Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("upload-button")).Displayed);
        IWebElement element = Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("upload-button"));
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Drivers._driverInstance;
        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    }
```

Same code was working on Friday on Firefox 54 and it still works in Chrome and IE.

Please let me know is there a workaround for the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue in geckodriver/marionette](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/858). The issue has been fixed in later versions of Firefox, and will require a new release of geckodriver. In the meantime, it's possible to work around the issue by setting the `dom.file.createInChild` preference to `true` in the `FirefoxOptions` you use when creating your Firefox session.

Comment: Thanks @JimEvans. This works as a temporary work around.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and got it resolved, the issue is within the Geckodriver and issue seems to be fixed ([check here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/858)), but you might need to wait for the release or you can use the beta version which I followed.

- Get the latest GeckoDriver
- Download version Firefox Setup 56.0b5

This should fix your problem and also make sure you are loading the correct version of the Firefox application while executing the test.